# textView and button wont fill screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a relative layout set to match_parent with a textView and button set to match_parent width and wrap_content height.

But in my emulator they don't fill the entire screen width, See in picture below they have white space around them.

[image: Emulator screenshot]

Layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:background="#ff000000"
    android:textColor="#ff12ff13" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Comment: Please show your layout file

Comment: And whats the issue with this layout ? Button and textview won't occupy the entire screen because you are using wrap_content on both button and textview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have padding on root layout to fill the screen use this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

Answer (score 2):

The white space you see is due to your padding in your RelativeLayout.. remove the padding if you want it to fill the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below 4 lines fro your relative layout

```
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove layout_padding in the relative layout, something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:background="#ff000000"
    android:textColor="#ff12ff13" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```